# How to get user details from bearer token laravel api

Tags: laravel, api, bearer-token

I can'understand how can I do so Please help me to find a solution

```
$response = $client->request('POST', '/api/profile_update', [
   
     'headers' => [
         'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
         'Accept' => 'application/json',
      ],
]);
return $response;
```

I used something like this in **`api.php`** file

now what can i do in **`controller`** file.

Comment: Welcome to so... use laravel sacntum https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: yes but how its actually work?

Comment: read the doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum it have all you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                  $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal token');
                    
                    $token = $tokenResult->token;
                    $token->save();
                    return response()->json([
                        'success'   => true,
                        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
                        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
                        )->toDateTimeString()
                  ]);
```

Answer (score -2):

you save user token in database-in user table and check it with given token from request

if they are same you get user information

Comment: is this solution ?

Comment: No it's not the soution